# Seperation of name[3:0] bus ito individual wire

Tags: linux, awk, sed, files

I have data like shown below

```
A[3:0] INPUT
B[3:0] OUTPUT
```

Now I want data as shown in below:

```
A[3] INPUT
A[2] INPUT
A[1] INPUT
A[0] INPUT
B[3] OUTPUT
B[2] OUTPUT
B[1] OUTPUT
B[0] OUTPUT
```

Any help?

Comment: you'll get help for code you tried, please add that to the question.. and give better sample, for example `A[3:0]` and corresponding expected output

Comment: post the extended output for this kind of input `A[3:0] INPUT
B[4:0] OUTPUT`

Answer (score 0):

**awk** approach:

```
awk '{ split($1,a,/[\[:]/); d=a[2]+1; while(d--) printf "%s[%d] %s\n",a[1],d,$2 }' file
```

The output:

```
A[3] INPUT
A[2] INPUT
A[1] INPUT
A[0] INPUT
B[3] OUTPUT
B[2] OUTPUT
B[1] OUTPUT
B[0] OUTPUT
```

Comment: title says `[9:0]` too.. am guessing it is vhdl/verilog where OP wants to convert bus into individual wires..

Comment: @Sundeep, yes, that should be elaborated

Comment: Exactly. I want to convert bus into idividual wires

Comment: @SureshBabuGoriparthi, see my update

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest,it is working absolutly.. Thanks for your help...